# Which product each customer bought the most?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, max, common-table-expression

I need to find the list of product that each customer bought the most along with customerid, productid and no of items bought.

Image showing table and desired results

[image: 1]

I tried this to count the no of products bought by each customer.

```
WITH cust_prod_ord AS (
SELECT customer_id,product_id, COUNT(product_id) as no_of_ord
FROM dannys_diner.sales
GROUP BY customer_id, product_id
ORDER BY customer_id )
```

Now I need to get the desired result as shown in image by using table created from above.

I tried this but I got different result.

```
SELECT customer_id, product_id, no_of_ord
FROM cust_prod_ord
WHERE no_of_ord = (SELECT MAX(no_of_ord) from cust_prod_ord)
```

I am not able to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `(SELECT MAX(no_of_ord) from cust_prod_ord)` in the `Where` clause, it will return the max of `no_of_ord` among all customers which is 3 in your sample data.

What you need is the max of `no_of_ord` for each customer, so you may fix your query as the following:

```
SELECT T.customer_id, T.product_id, T.no_of_ord
FROM cust_prod_ord T
WHERE 
T.no_of_ord = (SELECT MAX(no_of_ord) from cust_prod_ord where 
               customer_id=T.customer_id)
```

You may also try the following alternative to your query:

```
SELECT T.customer_id, T.product_id, T.no_of_ord
FROM cust_prod_ord T
Join
(
  Select customer_id,Max(no_of_ord) mx From cust_prod_ord
  Group By customer_id
) D
On T.customer_id = D.customer_id
And T.no_of_ord = D.mx
```

See a demo from *[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7WdAQN3jUjhFqSwjFMGnzy/0)*. (supposing that `cust_prod_ord` is a table)